# Windows batch file del does not delete

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to delete two directories using a batch file. There was no issue deleting these folders manually, and I was running the batch file as admin.

```
if exist C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Tableau\ del C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Tableau\  
if exist C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\TableauTemp\ del C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\TableauTemp\
```

The command window prompted in the following format for each folder:

```
if exist C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Tableau\ del C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Tableau\  
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Tableau\*, Are you sure (Y/N)?
```

After hitting Y, nothing happens and the folders are still there.

Comment: What happens if you try to delete the folder manually, not by script ? Seems to me something is preventing it from being deleted.

Comment: How about using the `RD` command instead.

Comment: Interesting point. There was no problem deleting the folders manually.

Comment: This Google search: **windows batch file delete directory** gives you this as the first [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490990.aspx)

Comment: @Squashman: thanks for the hint! I was searching along the lines of "batch file doesn't delete"; didn't know that deleting a file vs. a directory would make a difference. rd worked for me.

Comment: @user2271478, if you read the help file for the `DEL` command you will see this: **If a directory is specified, all files within the directory will be deleted.**  Does not say anything about deleting the directory itself.

Comment: Instead of using `if exist`, just delete the folder (using `rmdir`/`rd`), because if it does not exist, nothing is going to happen anyway; to suppress the path-not-found error message, append `2> nul` to the command line...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`del` can delete only empty folder. You need to use `rmdir /s` instead.

Comment: `del` does not delete folders, it only deletes files! To delete folders, `rmdir`/`rd` is required; switch `/S` allows to delete non-empty folders, switch `/Q` suppresses the yes/no prompt...